# Condition regex error

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
string=123456

if [ $string == 123456 ]; then
echo 123
fi
```

This works fine, but if I change == to =~ I get this error:

```
./test: line 3: [: =~: binary operator expected
```

Comment: The use of `=~` is in this case wrong. `=~` compares the patter (left side of the assignment) with a regular expresion `regex` on the right side of the assinment. A regular expression in its simplest form is passed like `'[0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @val0x00ff but `123456` is a valid RE

Comment: @roaima agreed, however regex is known for its engine, back-referencing, character-set, meta chars denoting starting of a string, ending of a string etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

***Bash***'s *regex* matching works only within double square brackets `[[ ... ]]`:

```
string=123456
if [[ "$string" =~ 123456 ]]; then echo 123; fi
123
```

Comment: @Kusalananda: Regarding the edit, the quotes are not required on the left hand side of a double bracket expression `[[ ... ]]`, since no word splitting or pathname expansion occurs there. They are only needed when using single brackets `[ ... ]` (both sides) and on the right hand of the double bracket expression.

Comment: @user000001 while you're correct, it's much better just to quote all variables by reflex unless there's a necessity not to. It's a much safer habit.

Comment: @Joe: Agreed, when in doubt, quote... I only mentioned this because it was an edit to an already correct answer. Had it been there from the first revision I would not have commented on this.